# Swift - Open UIViewController from within slide-in menu

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a slide-in menu that presents itself when I press the menu button in my navigation bar. Dismissing it can be accomplished by either tapping the background or the menu itself. Within this view I have several items, one of which is an user profile button. When I press this button, I want the menu to dismiss itself and then instantly open the user profile view controller. That's why I call **handleDismiss()** first and then set the view that needs to be opened

However, it keeps telling me that the view is not in the window hierarchy. I know what the problem is (view stack), but I somehow can't get it to work properly. How should I tackle this problem?

*RootViewController -> HomeController (tabBar index 0) -> Slide-In Menu -> UserProfileController*

**Button to open the controller**

```
profileCell.profileButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleUserProfile(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

**Functions**

```
func handleDismiss() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.blackView.alpha = 0

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
        }
    }
}

func handleUserProfile(sender: UIButton) {
    handleDismiss()

    let userProfileController = UserProfileController()
    openProfileController(userProfileController)
}

func openProfileController(_ controller: UIViewController) {
   present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by setting a reference to the rootViewController in my menu.

**HomeController**

```
let menuLauncher = MenuLauncher()

func tappedMenu(sender: UIButton) {
    menuLauncher.showMenu(self)
}
```

**MenuController**

```
func MenuLauncher() {
    self.m_ParentViewController = nil
}

func showMenu(_ parentViewController: UIViewController) {
    self.m_ParentViewController = parentViewController

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self

    collectionView.register(MenuLauncherImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdImage)
    collectionView.register(MenuLauncherInfoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdInfo)

    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)

        blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))

        window.addSubview(blackView)
        window.addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width, height: 350)

        blackView.frame = window.frame
        blackView.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.blackView.alpha = 1
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height - 350, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)

        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

func handleDismiss() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.blackView.alpha = 0

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
        }
    }
}

func handleUserProfile(sender: UIButton) {
    handleDismiss()

    let userProfileController = UserProfileController()
    self.m_ParentViewController?.present(userProfileController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```